# Issue Dynamically Populating Dropdown Using Node and Handlebars

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, handlebars.js

I am attempting to dynamically populate the dropdown on my template. I am adding company IDs to an array and then attempting to pass the array to the template.

Adding the IDs to the array:

```
var express = require('express');
//var mysql = require('./dbcon.js');


var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host  : 'localhost',
  user  : 'root',
  password: 'Baseball247!',
  database: 'award'
});


var app = express();
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', 3000);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/add-user', function(req,res){
  var context = {};
  pool.query("SELECT id from company;", function(err,rows,fields){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    context.results = rows;
    var companies = [];
    //console.log('The solution is: ', rows.length);
    for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      //console.log('The solution is: ', rows[i]["id"]);
      companies.push(rows[i]["id"]);
    }
    console.log(companies);
    res.render('addUser', {companies : companies});
  });
});
```

Then, I try to display those values in the dropdown via:

```
<select>
    <% for(var i=0; i < companies.length; i++) { %>
        <option><%= companies[i] %></option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

However, when I look at the web page the dropdown shows this instead of the company IDs:
[image]

When I `console.log` the array I see the correct results so I assume the issue is either with how I am passing the array or how I am traversing/calling the array in the template. Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: Where is the code that actually fills the template using the handlebars library?  Is it on the server or client and can you show that code please.

Comment: @JasonLivesay Maybe I'm confused. My code that I thought was populating my template using handlebars was the first block of code that is running on the server. The first block of code is from my server side code.

Comment: I dont see any code that references handlebars, where is that

Comment: @JasonLivesay I added it to the server side code above. Apologies if this is not what you are referencing.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the `select` should be:

```
    <p>Company: <select name="company" id="company">
    {{#each companies}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars uses curly braces not greater than percent.  Can you please check the basic documentation?  Thank you.